# How do I submit a new sub version to the apple app store?

Tags: ios, swift3, app-store

I was able to submit a fresh app to the store, but I cannot for the life of me find a button where I can submit a new version?

[image]

does it automatically submit the app when I upload the archive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new version (Plus button):

[image]

It all flows from there; just start filling out the forms.

Comment: ugh, now it makes sense.  I assumed it would create that automatically